# Compiling a Windows 8 minifilter Driver for Windows 7

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, driver, wdk, minifilter

Is it possible to compile [AVScan Minifilter](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/AvScan-File-System-40053812#content) given in the MSDN Sample  for Windows 7? as it's target client is Windows 8. I am using Visual Studio 2013 with WDK 8.1, the sample project don't have Win7 Debug/Release in the configuration manager. if it is possible how can it be done? Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar (had to build change minifilter driver for win 7 x64). I just copied the settings from the project file of minispy fs minifilter driver, which had the working win7 configuration. So what you need to do is:

- Add a new configuration in config manager called "Win7 Debug". Save and close.
- Open the AVScan minifilter C++ project in notepad
- Overwrite these sections in the project file:

  ```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Win7 Debug|x64'" Label="Configuration">
  <TargetVersion>Win7</TargetVersion>
  <UseDebugLibraries>True</UseDebugLibraries>
  <DriverType>WDM</DriverType>
  <PlatformToolset>WindowsKernelModeDriver8.1</PlatformToolset>
  <ConfigurationType>Driver</ConfigurationType>
  </PropertyGroup>


  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Win7 Debug|x64'">
  <Link>
    <AdditionalOptions>%(AdditionalOptions) /map</AdditionalOptions>
    <AdditionalDependencies>%(AdditionalDependencies);$(DDK_LIB_PATH)\fltMgr.lib</AdditionalDependencies>
  </Link>
  <ClCompile>
    <TreatWarningAsError>true</TreatWarningAsError>
    <WarningLevel>Level4</WarningLevel>
    <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories);..\inc</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
    <PreprocessorDefinitions>%(PreprocessorDefinitions);_WIN2K_COMPAT_SLIST_USAGE</PreprocessorDefinitions>
    <ExceptionHandling>
    </ExceptionHandling>
  </ClCompile>
  <ResourceCompile>
    <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories);..\inc</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
    <PreprocessorDefinitions>%(PreprocessorDefinitions);_WIN2K_COMPAT_SLIST_USAGE</PreprocessorDefinitions>
  </ResourceCompile>
  <Midl>
    <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories);..\inc</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
    <PreprocessorDefinitions>%(PreprocessorDefinitions);_WIN2K_COMPAT_SLIST_USAGE</PreprocessorDefinitions>
  </Midl>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  ```
- Save and close.
- Open in VS and build!

Comment: after making the mentioned changes, the project fails to load

Comment: Maybe you are missing an xml tag. Can you open the project file and check if you are indeed missing one? In the answer above the `</PropertyGroup>` tag was missing. I have added it now.

Comment: Yeh I have already closed the tag, but still the problem persist, it is unable to load the project

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to have a separate binary for Windows 7 or different version of the OS with a few conditions.

Driver binaries are just plain old executable files just like DLLs or EXEs. They have a PE header IAT etc.

As long as your compiled driver does not attempt  to call APIs which were not supported in that OS you should be OK.
For those APIs or functions simply dynamically load them if the version you are running on supports them via [MmGetSystemRoutineAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-mmgetsystemroutineaddress) or [FltGetRoutineAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/fltkernel/nf-fltkernel-fltgetroutineaddress).

So, simply compile your driver with version of lowest OS you plan to support and good luck from there.

Cheers,
Gabriel